# Is it possible to extend a singleton (object declaration) in Kotlin?

Tags: inheritance, kotlin, singleton

I have an [object declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html) (`object A : BaseClass`) and I want to create another object declaration `B` that inherits from `A`'s implicit class. `BaseClass` is a class and not an interface. Is it possible in Kotlin?

Answer (score 11):

You can use delegation. Note that you can only delegate via interface, so you'll need to create an interface with subset of methods you need to delegate through.

```
interface Iface {
   fun doStuff()
}

object BaseObject: Iface {
   override fun doStuff() { }
}

class BaseClass: Iface {
   override fun doStuff() { }
}

object ExtendedObjectDelegatingToObject: Iface by BaseObject {
   fun doSomethingElse() { }
}

object ExtendedObjectDelegatingToClass: Iface by BaseClass() {
   fun doSomethingElse() { }
}

class ExtendedClassDelegatingToObject: Iface by BaseObject {
   fun doSomethingElse() { }
}

class ExtendedClassDelegatingToClass: Iface by BaseClass() {
   fun doSomethingElse() { }
}

fun example() {
    BaseObject.doStuff() // can call doStuff from BaseObject
    ExtendedObjectDelegatingToObject.doStuff() // can call doStuff from ExtendedObject
    ExtendedObjectDelegatingToObject.doSomethingElse() // can also call additional methods on ExtendedObject
}
```

Comment: Can I use delegation if the base for both objects is a class? (I've edited the question to include this detail)

Comment: @SpaceBison you can delegate classes as well, yes

Comment: I meant something like this: `class BaseClass {}` `object DelegateObject : BaseClass {}` `object ExtendedObject : BaseClass() by DelegateObject {}`. I'm getting a "Only interfaces can be delegated to" error, so I guess it's not possible. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @SpaceBison yes, only interfaces can be delegated.